# How many different products can we get using the first n natural number?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial, factoring

Let $U=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ and $s$ to be an non-empty subset of $U$, let $prod$ be a function on set to calculate the product of all elements in a set.

My question is, what is the number of elements in $\{prod(s)\}$.

For example, if $n=4$, then there is $\{1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24\}$.

Note that the answer isn't just the number of factors of $n!$.

It confused me a lot. Could anyone help me with it

Comment: It's [A060957](https://oeis.org/A060957)

Comment: @Sil The OP is not counting the empty product.

Comment: @user2661923 That does not change anything, empty product gives just a result of $1$ which will be there anyway.

Comment: @Sil You are right, my mistake.  I have deleted my answer.

Comment: @Sil Thanks a lot. I did try to search on OEIS and it seems failed since I didn't count the empty set in. So, this means that we don't have an explicit expression for it and we can only count it in a really brute force way?

Comment: As Sil indicated, you can ignore the empty set, since that is covered by the subset $\{1\}.$

Comment: OEIS might not be complete, I would take it as a starting point at least (though it's likely that if simple formula was known it would be there...)

Comment: may I know why the answer is not the number of factors of $n!$?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple formula known for this difficult problem.

Consider $A(n,k)$ the number of products of $k$ elements from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}.$ For $k=2,$ this is the famous *Erdos Multiplication Table* problem. Your question is essentially the size of the *union* of the sets $A(n,k),$ for $1\leq k\leq \sqrt{n}.$

The best known general result for $k=2$ is a recent asymptotic estimate (for $x$ large) due to Ford:

> The number of positive integers $n\le x$, which can be written as $n=m_1m_2$, with each
> $m_i\le\sqrt x$, is bounded above and below by a constant times $$x(\log x)^{-\delta}(\log\log x)^{-3/2},$$ where  $\delta=1-(1+\log\log2)/\log2$.

To translate to your question take $x=n^2,$ which would give
$$O\left(\frac{n}{(2\log n)^{\delta}(\log(2 \log n))^{3/2}}\right),$$
as the number of 2-way products.

For $k\leq 5,$ there are estimates known, but that's it. The same question and its answers has some discussion concerning algorithms to compute this quantity for fixed $k.$

See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31663/distinct-numbers-in-multiplication-table/31666) on mathoverflow for more.